# Copy directory structure + files, but to exclude files that contain backup word in their file name

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to copy directory structure + specific files, but at same time to exclude files from the chosen types that contain the word "backup" in their name.
This statement

```
Get-ChildItem "F:\rbf" -include *.txt, *.svc -Recurse |
    ? {$_.fullname -notmatch '\\backup\\'} |
    % {Copy-Item $_.fullname "D:\New\"}
```

copies the desired files and excludes the not wanted ones, but I need to keep the entire directory tree as well.

Comment: try using `-Exclude` with wildcards `*backup*`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply, but I do not have problem with the exclude part, I need to figure out how while excluding and copying the files to keep the entire directory structure, where the files are stored. The line up just copies my files, but not the dir. structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = "F:\rbf"
$destination = "D:\New"

# Create the directory structure first
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
            ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ }

# Then copy relevant files
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -recurse -include *.txt, *.svc -exclude *backup* |
            Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer } |
            Copy-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel in PowerShell.

This will copy all .txt and .svc files unless they have the string "backup" in their filename:

```
robocopy F:\rbf D:\New *.txt *.svc /s /xf *backup*
```

This will copy all .txt and .svc files unless they are located in a directory named "backup":

```
robocopy F:\rbf D:\New *.txt *.svc /s /xd backup
```

Answer (score -2):

Copy-Item also has include and exclude:

```
Copy-Item -path F:\rbf -Destination D:\New\ -exclude *backup* -recurse
```

This should copy the files you want with directory structure and not copy the backup files.

Comment: That will keep the directory structure intact, but `-Exclude` doesn't work the way you seem to expect.

Comment: I tested on PowerShell v2 and v4 and can assure you that it doesn't. If you use `-Path F:\rbf\*` it excludes top-level files and folders that have the string "backup" in their name, but it doesn't do the same for files/folders nested in subdirectories.

Comment: Tested on v5 without the star, copies all folders and files except any file that has backup in the name down to 4 subdirectories.  leaves folders which have backup in the name.  I'll test on v2 and 4 as you have as well

Comment: Since the OP tagged the question [tag:powershell-v3.0] I wouldn't consider PowerShell v5 behavior relevant here.